# How to decrement a column value in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, controller, shopping-cart

This is the query i am using:

```
$number = DB::table('products')->where('id', '=', $product->id)->update(['quantity' => 'quantity', '-', 1 ]);
```

Please help me with the right syntax. I want to subtract 1 from the current value of quantity column. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use [decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#increment-and-decrement) method for this;

> The query builder also provides convenient methods for incrementing or decrementing the value of a given column. This is a shortcut, providing a more expressive and terse interface compared to manually writing the update statement.

```
DB::table('products')->where('id', $product->id)->decrement('quantity');
```